# Macro prompts me to choose file even when its open

Tags: excel, vba

I have hard coded file name (old.xls) in my macro (in another workbook). old.xls is already open when I execute the macro. Even then  the below line prompts me to choose a file.

```
.Formula = "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(Q1, 2, 1))),LEFT(TRIM(Q1), 1) = ""R""),VLOOKUP(Q1 & "" *"",[old.xls]Sheet1!$D:$V,19,0),VLOOKUP(Q1,[old.xls]Sheet1!$E:$V,18,0))"
```

Please advise. Why isn't the macro referring old.xls which is already open? Why does it ask me to choose old.xls every time?

Every time I run the macro Excel prompts me with an open file menu.

Comment: Hi, Check whether macro & old.xls files are opened in same instance of excel & also check whether both files are in same path becuase you didnt given full path of the file in the formula

Comment: Macro and old.xls are opened in same instance and also belong to the same path

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Are you sure both files are already saved when the formula is inserted? Can you build a [mcve] to reproduce it, or can you provide a list of steps what **exactly** you do, starting from a closed Excel ending with inserting this formula? • Please also verify if Excel also asks you for the file, if you enter the formula manually into the cell.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the macro & its works fine. request you to check the error is in this line or any other line.

Comment: I debugged and found this issue at this line

Comment: @user8107531 If you expect help from us you must help us to find your issue. Please read my comment above again.

Comment: I voted to close the question due to this comment: *"I just found the cause. "old" file extension was causing this issue."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you should test full reference:

```
 Dim test As String  
 test = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"  
 'your WITH block code...
   .Formula = "=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(Q1, 2, 1))),LEFT(TRIM(Q1), 1) = ""R""),VLOOKUP(Q1 & "" *"",'" & test & "[old.xls]Sheet1'!$D:$V,19,0),VLOOKUP(Q1,'" & test & "[old.xls]Sheet1'!$E:$V,18,0))"
```

If still there is a prompt I would close old.xls file and check simple file open:

```
 Sub openTest()
   Dim test As String
   test = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\old.xls"
   Workbooks.Open (test)
 End Sub
```

Comment: I just found the cause. "old" file extension was causing this issue.